# Java sqlite database is locked

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to delete a student from database, but I got this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: database is locked
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:859)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.exec(DB.java:142)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.commit(JDBC3Connection.java:165)
    at Controller.deleteStudent(Controller.java:232)
    at Test$9.actionPerformed(Test.java:227)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I read other posts on stackoverflow and all of them said that all connections needs to be closed to open a new connection. I did this, but I still got the same problem.

Here's my code:

```
public static void deleteStudent(int id) {
    try {
        con = null;
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = null;
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        int result = stmt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM STUDENTS WHERE ID=" + id + ";");
        System.out.println(result);
        con.commit();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
        output();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Do you have ideas why I still get this error?

Comment: You should always `close()` the connection in a `finally` block.

Comment: I already did this but it's the same thing.

Comment: @andreicovaciu If you take Lance's advice and use proper `try-catch` blocks, my guess is that you will see a reason why the database is not being unlocked.

Comment: sqlite's single-user. any other processes using that test.db file?

Comment: I already tried in a finally block try-catch to put there stmt.close() and con.close()

Comment: @MarcB insertion works

Comment: So you verified that _every_ line of the `try` block is being executed with no error?

Comment: reboot your machine or try to find out which program is locking your database. On Windows you can use sysinternals tools for this.

Comment: Is your insertion method `close()`ing the connection in a `finally` block? I get the feeling you need to go through all your code and check that connections are being closed properly. You might consider using spring's [jdbctemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) or similar to avoid connection leaks

Comment: @LanceJava This is why I think he should be using proper JDBC code to do the deletion.

Comment: All my  `close()`ing method are not in a  `finally`block.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen He's using JDBC? What's your definition of "proper"?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I use sqlite

Comment: Actually, I think the better question is what's my definition of JDBC.  But his code looks OK as I just checked the docs now.  Strange that there is no exception.

Comment: @andreicovaciu I suggest you either use Spring's JDBCTemplate or implement a similar pattern. I recently rolled-my-own JDBCTemplate [here](https://github.com/uklance/tader/blob/master/tader-core/src/main/java/org/tader/jdbc/JdbcTemplateImpl.java) since I didn't want a spring dependency. You can easliy do the same

Comment: I also want you to know that the `result` output is 1.

Comment: That's irrelevant... the `commit()` is failing, not the `executeUpdate()`. I'm guessing that another process is locking the file so the `commit()` can't proceed.